# Angular 2+ and geting data from htttp to behaviour subject in service

Tags: angular

I have created planets.service and I want to get data from http and next put in in behaviourSubject. In next step, I want to subscribe planets$ in different components. I am getting error:

```
AppComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

Does somebody know how ot fix it?

Planets.service.ts:

```
export class PlanetsService {    
    private _planetsUrl: string = "https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json";

    planets$: Subject<any>;

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this.getPlanetsFromUrl().subscribe(planets => {
            this.planets$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(planets);
            console.log(planets);
        });
    }

    getPlanetsFromUrl() {
        return this._http.get(this._planetsUrl)
            .map( (response: Response) => response.json().results )
    }
}
```

App.component.ts :

```
planets: any[];

ngOnInit() {
    this._planetsService.planets$.subscribe(planets => {
        this.planets = planets;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
planets$: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>()

constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.getPlanetsFromUrl().subscribe(planets => {
        this.planets$.next(planets);
        console.log(planets);
    });
}
```

You're assigning the subject in the `subscribe` callback. Which happens *after* the `ngOnInit` of the component because it's an HTTP response.

Assign the new `BehaviorSubject` to the property when the service is created, and then call `next` to emit values.

Comment: What is planets in new BehaviorSubject<any>(planets)?

Comment: @prehistorycznapomarancza I removed it. My mistake.

Comment: ReplaySubject can act as a BehaviourSubject without needing an initial value, sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: I think, normal Subject will fit it better

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of `Subject` and assign it to `planet$`. What you have done is just created the `reference`, which is not an `instance` of `Subject`

```
planets$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
```

Your code inside `ngOnInit()` will run before the `this.getPlanetsFromUrl()` method has returned. Which means you are trying to access before assigning a object of `Subject`. So it is best you create instance during declaration as shown above.

And simply emit from your service file as `this.planets$.next(planets);`

```
constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this.getPlanetsFromUrl().subscribe(planets => {
            this.planets$.next(planets);
            console.log(planets);
        });
}
```